# active object in python for s60

Tags: python, pys60, active-objects

How do I use active object in python for s60?
can anybody give me a code example?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's a simple example [here](http://epx.com.br/artigos/pys60.php):

```
def run(self):
    self.lock = e32.Ao_lock()
    self.lock.wait()
    # restore old title etc. and finish

def exit_callback(self):
    # unlocks the application and lets it finish
    self.lock.signal()
```

and that same URL also contains a detailed explanation (and more info, tutorial and otherwise, on Python for S60).

Comment: I write this in the source code and then run it On pythonScriptShell

Comment: there is an option to run script